# Neo4J: Joining back and forth in Cypher

Tags: database, join, neo4j, cypher, northwind

I have the following Nodes in a Neo4J DB (Northwind DB):

- `Customer`
- `Order`
- `Product`

The nodes have the following relationship:

 `(c:Customer)-->(o:Order)--> (p:Product)`

How can I get the `Products`, and the count of the products, that have been bought by `Customers`, who also bought a `Product` with `pr_ID`=2?

I have tried the following query. It returns the correct items, but the wrong counts:

```
MATCH (p:Product)<--(o:Order)<--(c:Customer) 
WITH p,o,c WHERE p.productID='2' 
MATCH c-->(od:Order)-->(pr:Product) 
WITH c,od,pr WHERE NOT pr.productID='2' 
RETURN pr.productName, count(pr.productName)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter the product id before passing them with the WITH :

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-->(o:Order)-->(p:Product {productId: '2'})
MATCH (c)-->(:Order)-->(p2:Product)
WHERE p2 <> p
RETURN p2.productName, count(*) as c
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my query did not work, was that I used `count(pr.productName)` instead of `count(DISTINCT od)`.